# A valid way to find out if a language voice is installed in TextToSpeech

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to let the user select the accent of TextToSpeech (British, American) in my app. But the method `isLanguageAvailable` always returns the code 1 (`LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE`) for `Locale.US` and `Locale.UK` even when one of the language data is not available. I have tried it on different devices and different situations but it doesn't have an stable result and I wanna know if there is any other way to understand an specific locale is installed on a device (Considering the fact that my min API version is 16 I can not use `getAvailableLanguages`)

**===UPDATE====**

So far I have figured that apparently the concept of Language availability and  Language voices are different. Apparently a language can be available without any voice data (which is funny btw). But even in that case I wanna know if there is any voice available for a language in API16

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @BakonJarser Unfortunately not, And I gave up. It's the user's problem now )))